# Exception for ContextLoaderListener after changing to newer spring-web

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

My project was having spring-web-3.0.0.RC3. But for introducing Spring Session I gave the dependency of spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE. From then I am getting error. I was expecting after adding newer Spring-web older code should work as it is. I am getting following error on the startup

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:345)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at
```

My pom.xml

<

```
!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                    </exclusion> 
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Session JDBC -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- DB Connectors -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You cannot update 1 part of Spring you will have to update all your Spring dependencies to 5.0.7.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by not taking spring-web 5.0.7.I used only spring-session-jdbc and that pulled spring web 4.0 also . And then all the Spring versions became of same version and it worked